# Pass variable to vuejs module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, vuejs2, vue-component

I was using the event emitter from vue to make the main app talk to the components and it was working as long as I had the app and all the components in one .js file.

But now I wish to have them separated, one component per file, and obviously I cannot use the event emitter anymore, because the `app` appears undefined in the modules.

What do I need to change to be able have the app and components communicate again?

My code:

my-app.js

```
import My from '/my-module.js';

const app = new Vue({
  router: new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [{
      path: '/',
      component: My,
    }]),

  methods: {

    created(){
       this.ws = new WebSocket(...);
       this.ws.onmessage = event => {
         this.$emit('message', e);
       }
    }

  }

}).$mount('#app');
```

my-module.js

```
export default {

  template: `....`

  created(){
    // I want to be able to access 'app' here
    // or another way to receive the messages
    console.log(app);
    app.$on('message', ...)

  }    

}
```

As you can see I only need this because I'm using websockets and the app holds the websocket client. The components need to do something when certain messages are received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you may use those events in multiple components, specialy when app is still growing. i think you better use `eventbus` to `emit` and `catch` all of them.

here how to use `eventbus` in vuejs : https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/.

in you're case :

```js
import { eventBus } from 'path/to/file';

...

methods: {
    created(){
       this.ws = new WebSocket(...);
       this.ws.onmessage = event => {
         eventBus.$emit('message', e);
       }
    }
}
```

Other component :

```js
import { eventBus } from 'path/to/file';
...

created() {
  eventBus.$on('message',() => ) {
    // code
  }
}
```